# Displaying Nested Models in Marionette

Tags: json, nested, marionette

I'm sending a nested model as JSON to a Marionette app. It looks something like this:

```
{

    "Course1": [
        {
            "id": 51,
            "title": "Assignment1",
            "created_at": "2013-09-01T08:47:37.908+09:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-09-09T20:53:00.193+09:00",
        },
        {
            "id": 52,
            "title": "Assignment2",
            "created_at": "2013-09-01T09:11:40.547+09:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-09-09T20:52:37.630+09:00",
        }
    ],
    "Course2": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "title": "Assignment1",
            "created_at": "2013-08-08T22:49:26.621+09:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-09-09T20:48:20.015+09:00",
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "title": "Assignment2",
            "created_at": "2013-08-08T23:03:58.131+09:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-09-09T20:47:53.997+09:00",
        }
    ],
    "Course3": [
        {
            "id": 29,
            "title": "Assignment1",
            "created_at": "2013-08-18T09:22:32.299+09:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-09-09T20:47:32.971+09:00",
        },
        {
            "id": 30,
            "title": "Assignment2",
            "created_at": "2013-08-18T09:33:16.882+09:00",
            "updated_at": "2013-09-09T20:02:08.731+09:00",
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm wondering if there is some way to display each "course" and the data nested within the courses as a table in a Marionette view. I don't know how many courses I'll be sending to Marionette on any given request.

Is there some way to iterate over the data above (as a collection in the Marionette app) and dynamically make a new CompositeView for each course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now how foolish I was! What I was trying to do is part of the core Backbone.Marionette functionality.

I needed only to nest the List.Assignments CompositeView inside the List.Courses CompositeView.

```
@ControlPanel.module "AssignmentsApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class List.Controller extends Marionette.Controller

    initialize: ->
      # This is a collection of courses with nested assignments
      # as described in the original question.
      App.request "courses:entities", (courses) =>

        @coursesView = @getCoursesView courses
        App.mainRegion.show @coursesView

    getCoursesView: (courses) ->
      new List.Courses
        collection: courses


  class List.Assignment extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "assignments/list/templates/assignment"
    tagName: "li"

  class List.Assignments extends Marionette.CompositeView
    template: "assignments/list/templates/assignments"
    tagName: "li"
    itemView: List.Assignment
    itemViewContainer: "ul"

    # This is the important part...
    initialize: ->
      # Get the nested assignments for this particular course
      assignments = @model.get("assignments")
      # At this point assignments is a regular Javascript object.
      # For this to work assignments must be a valid Backbone collection
      @collection = new Backbone.collection assignments

  class List.Courses extends Marionette.CompositeView
    template: "assignments/list/templates/courses"
    itemView: List.Assignments
    itemViewContainer: "ul"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Underscore `each` function. Something like this:

```
var data = <your JSON data here>;

_.each(data, function(value, key, list) {
  var compView = new <yourCustomCompositeView>({ collection: value });
  // render the view in whatever region you need to
});
```

That would create a new CompositeView for each entry in your JSON. Here's the documenation for that function: http://underscorejs.org/#each

**Update**
Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/craigjennings11/D2qAC/ on a way to solve this. It might not be the cleanest, but it gets the job done. Note that I specify a custom region that overloads the `open` method for the layout, and then call `open` to attach the views to the region instead of `show`. `show` closes the region before calling `open` again, which would remove your previous view.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. Edited my original question to take into account your answer.

Comment: You probably need to set up `@layout.assignmentsRegion.open` to append the view to the region. By default, it replaces the contents of the region with the view, hence why you're only seeing one composite view. See [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#set-how-views-el-is-attached) for documentation.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far with this. Can you check Edit 2 in the original question?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I ended up solving this issue with just the core Backbone.Marionette functionality.